# OneDrive Graph API: Get User ID associated with drive ID

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-files

I have an ID of an OneDrive drive. Is there any way I can figure out the user ID to whom the OneDrive drive belongs to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call

```
GET /drives/{drive-id}
```

it returns [Drive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/resources/drive?view=odsp-graph-online) resource type with `Owner` property. It's the user account that owns the drive and it includes user id.

```
{
    "id": "b!t18F8ybsHUq1z3LTz8xvZqP8zaSWjkFNhsME-Fepo75dTf9vQKfeRblBZjoSQrd7",
    "driveType": "business",
    "owner": {
        "user": {
            "id": "efee1b77-fb3b-4f65-99d6-274c11914d12",
            "displayName": "John Doe"
        }
    },
    ...
}
```